# How to increase the draw distance in the Bethesda (Gamebryo engine) Fallout games?

Tags: pc, fallout-new-vegas, fallout-3

The grass draw distance was extremely limited in Oblivion, but Fallout 3 and New Vegas still have quite noticeable issues with loading (streaming?) their sparse landscape. I've maxed out all related sliders in the options menu.

The related .ini variables apparently are (`15` is the highest in-game setting):

```
fObjectLODMax=
fItemLODMax=
fActorLODMax=
```

According to some reports the settings can be increased manually, with a performance and a potential stability impact of course — that's why Bethesda capped the in-game values.

The .ini files are located in `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\Fallout3\` and `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\FalloutNV\`. Visit [PC Gaming Wiki](https://www.pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Engine:Gamebryo_(TES_Engine)) for further information.

---

**UPDATE**: [The GOG versions have some values increased over the original releases](https://forum.step-project.com/topic/8957-fallout-3-default-values-for-all-valid-ini-settings/).

Comment: To anyone who doesn't own the games, the GOG versions have additional fixes such as the 4 GB memory patch applied, if you prefer not to tweak manually. And Fallout 3 doesn't use [GFWL](https://www.pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Games_for_Windows_-_LIVE) there.

Comment: Based on the body of the question, I assumed you were talking about the drawing distance of grass, specifically, but you're asking after the drawing distance of everything?

Comment: @Joachim: Yes, I asked about the draw distance in general and only gave the grass as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [a Gamerpoets video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ond4glt6pPw), the relevant settings in Fallout 3 and their increased values are:

in `Fallout.ini`

```
fNearDistance=8
bForceFullLOD=1
```

in `FalloutPrefs.ini`

```
fGrassStartFadeDistance=18000
fLODFadeOutMultActors=15
fLODFadeOutMultItems=10
fLODFadeOutMultObjects=15
fTreeLoadDistance=250000
fBlockLoadDistanceLow=250000
```

I wasn't able to make any difference by raising `fObjectLODMax`, `fItemLODMax` and `fActorLODMax` to `30`. I'm unsure if the settings work in Fallout 3.

As said in the original question, GOG raised some graphical settings, improved compatibility on modern systems and disabled mouse acceleration when the games were released on GOG in 2017. You can still apply the same tweaks manually in the other versions, but Games for Windows - LIVE (GFWL) may cause issues since the service isn't supported by Microsoft anymore.

---

I'll verify later if the same tweaks apply to New Vegas. This answer only covers Fallout 3.

Answer (score 3):

In '*FalloutPrefs.ini*':

- Under the `[Grass]` section:
  `fGrassStartFadeDistance`: the higher this number, the further away the grass will be drawn. A value of 18000 will set it to 5 cells, for example.

Additional vegetative tweaks, in '*Fallout.ini*':

- Under the `[Grass]` section:
  `iMinGrassSize`: decrease this value to improve the grass density.
  `iMaxGrassTypesPerTexure` (the misspelling is supposed to be there):  increase this to get a wider variety of textures.

Naturally, all improvements come at a performance cost.
And, as always, be sure to create backups of your .ini files.

---

[Here](https://wiki.step-project.com/Guide:SkyrimPrefs_INI/Grass) is an overview of these values pertaining to Skyrim (the parameters work exactly the same, if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: I assume that the grass commands don't affect the draw distance of objects/items/characters/shadows? I'll go through [the Gamerpoet video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ond4glt6pPw) tomorrow.

Comment: No, they don't, they're exclusive to grass.